# Drupal 7, Creating widget with ImageField and a Textarea

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Can anyone help me figure out how can i create a widget(Field API) which will contain an image(i want to to be an ImageField) and a textarea in Drupal 7?
Unfortunately i cannot find any tutorial how to do this on google.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you want group of fields? http://drupal.org/project/field_collection

Comment: hmmm no, because i want it to be a field, so i can use the power of the FIELD API. For example, i want this field to be show unlimited on a content field...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for not closing this. but the real answer to this is to use Field Collection module - drupal.org/project/field_collection. You add multiple field to this. When i asked this question i was new to D7 and in D6 we had to write this by hand. great module!

Answer (score 7):

There's no tutorial as such that I know of, but have a look at the [Drupal Examples Module](http://drupal.org/project/examples), there's a module within called `field_example` with all of the info you need.

On a very basic level you want to do this:

1. Implement [hook_field_schema()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.api.php/function/hook_field_schema/7) in your module's `.install` file to define what columns are going to be held in your field table (probably file ID (`fid`), alternative text for the image, title text for the image and the contents of the text area in your case).
2. Implement [hook_field_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.api.php/function/hook_field_info/7) to define your field type.
3. Implement [hook_field_is_empty()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.api.php/function/hook_field_is_empty/7) to provide a way for Drupal to know that a particular instance of a field is empty and can be removed when the entity is saved.
4. Implement [hook_field_formatter_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.api.php/function/hook_field_formatter_info/7) to tell Drupal the different ways the content of your field can be displayed.
5. Implement [hook_field_formatter_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.api.php/function/hook_field_formatter_view/7) to define exactly how those field formatters defined in step 4 will be outputted.
6. Implement [hook_field_widget_info](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_info/7) to define the different input widgets for your field.
7. Implement [hook_field_widget_form](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_form/7) to define the elements that will make up the widget for your field.

Once you've jumped through all of those hoops (it doesn't actually take that long to implement, most functions are just a few lines of code), enable the module and start adding your new field to entities!

Answer (score 1):

you should start from this 2 hook to create the widget.
then you should start creating the compound field

hook_field_widget_info()
hook_field_widget_form(&$form, &$form_state, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $delta, $element)

here are some link to create custom field and widget 
http://www.phase2technology.com/node/1495/
http://drupal.org/project/dnd_character

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at this [tutorial](http://evolvingweb.ca/story/poutine-maker-introduction-field-api-drupal-7-part-1). Most other ones the writer concentrates on sounding clever, this one has screenshots and is very clear and concise.