# Drupal 7 - Custom Field for radion button with images

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-theming

In Drupal 7, is it possible to add custom field like below in article node?

These values should be fetched from taxonomy terms

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible.
What you need to do is to create widget for term reference or entityreference field(if you have module entityreferenceinstalled).
You can read about how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544374/drupal-7-creating-widget-with-imagefield-and-a-textarea).